# Abstract state in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am new to the Ionic framework. I am using the ionic tabs. This tabs works fine.

```
.state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })
```

I want to know the meaning of `abstract` here. What does `abstract` do? If I set `abstarct:false` or comment this then this also works without any effect.

Comment: abstract : true means you will have child pages and you will be parent.
abstract:false means you will not able to create child pages, mostly we will use this functionality in tabs

Answer (score 1):

It is the feature of `angular-ui-router` but not `ionic`. Please see it here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views#abstract-states

From the docs:

> An abstract state can have child states but can not get activated
>   itself. An 'abstract' state is simply a state that can't be
>   transitioned to. It is activated implicitly when one of its
>   descendants are activated.
>
> Some examples of how you might use an abstract state are:
>
> 1. To prepend a url to all child state urls.
> 2. To provide resolved dependencies via resolve for use by
>      child states.
> 3. To provide inherited custom data via data for use by
>      child states or an event listener.
> 4. To run an onEnter or onExit
>      function that may modify the application in someway.
>      4.Any combination
>      of the above.